# how to control the output of a generator of a gan model

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am implementing a gan model from text embeddings
, my original images are of shape 3 * 512 * 512
I want my generator to produce images of the same shape
 currently it produces images of 3 * 512 * 4096
 my input shape for the generator is 8 *  16 * 128
I thought about resizing the images but that wouldn't be right I think.
this is my generator s architecture

```py
 nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 16, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32,64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 3, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            )
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, and add more details. You are saying that it's already producing 3* 512* 512 shape and you want 3 *512*512 shape !!! Also what is the shape of your inputs?

Comment: yes you are right I am sorry i just  edited my question

Comment: You can do this in many ways, for example you can use `rectangle conv` instead of square ones. You can also use linear model at the start, project the last dim into 16, or as you say just reshape it. Which one better, need experiments